# Does a proxy needed for a cross domain Ajax call if no return is expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, proxy, cross-domain

I have a tracking system sending Ajax Call to a remote server in JavaScript. No return values from the server is expected.

This is the Ajax call :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    $.ajax({
       url: "https://remoteURL.com/r/",
       type: "get",
       async: false,
       xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
       },
       data: {
          tagid: "123"  
       }
    }).done(function () {
       console.log("sent");
    });
};
```

Google Chrome show that the request was successfully sent :

[image]

The problem is that I didn't get the `sent` console log, but this error:

```
Failed to load https://remoteURL.com/r/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://myWebSite.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have no access to the external server, so I cannot change the header.

If I'm not expecting any return from the remote URL called in Ajax, is this code still functional despite the error thrown in console regarding the cross domain policy ?

Comment: No, regardless of if you expect a response back or not, CORS is intended to restrict access where it should not be allowed.  In this case, the offsite endpoint has not allowed your domain to access it remotely via ajax.

Comment: Why are you using `done` at all when you have `async: false`?

Comment: Yes, your code is functional - it just cannot access the results. Do you actually need that "sent" to get logged?

Comment: @Bergi no I don't need the .done() callback, but when I remove it doesn't change much

Answer (score 0):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a restriction made by browsers, so the request was not sent. To do that kind of tracking (without sending the request from a server) you could use `ping` attribute of `<a>`  like this:

```
<a href="https://example" ping="https://example/trackpings">
```

That ping send a void post request to https://example/trackpings in this case.